# Unallocated space from windows 7 to Ubuntu

Tags: gparted, disk-usage, unallocated

I shrank my `/dev/sda1` using windows 7 partition program and I want to extend `/dev/sda3` with that unallocated space. I know I have to use a live Ubuntu cd/usb and use gparted. But I can't seem to manage adding that space to `/dev/sda3`.

Can someone please help me?
[image: gparted screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can move the Windows `/dev/sda2` partition to the left, from one of your installations or the live disk. You may want to do this from a Windows disk manager if it has the Windows bootloader in.

Then you can expand `/dev/sda3` and then the `/dev/sda5` to the left from the live disk.

Answer (score 1):

1. First open Gparted.
2. Now unmount the partition you want to resize.
3. Right click on the partion and select resize.
4. A popup with that partition will appear.
5. Now drag the  rectangle side into the unallocated space.
   6.Click ok.

Comment: The problem with that is you can't unmount the partitions the system is running off - i.e. `/dev/sda3` & `/dev/sda5`, possibly `/dev/sda6`.

Comment: Then boot in live mode using ubuntu disk or usb.

Comment: I booted in live mode and unmounted /dev/sda3 but I still cannot resize it with the unallocated space.

Comment: Sorry for not noticing  one thing that unallocated space is not adjacent to `/dev/sda3`and you can't resize it untill unallocated is not between /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3. So try to make space beetween them and then resize it. Here is a good tutorial which would be help full for you.http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions